# R JDBC snowflake connection using ssh key auth

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

I have a Rstudio setup with no browser and only terminal access to internet.

Having issues following the guides for snowflake connections with Rstudio and dplyr library using ssh keys for auth, can confirm access to the tenant via browser outside of terminal. I also tried the jdbcDriver jar directly and connection to no avail.

Any pointers would be helpful

Examples below, tried with and without region

```
install.packages(c("rJava"))
install.packages(c("RJDBC", "DBI", "dplyr"))
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("snowflakedb/dplyr-snowflakedb")
library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr.snowflakedb)
options(dplyr.jdbc.classpath = "/opt/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar")

snowflake_con <- src_snowflakedb(user = "myusername@domain.comm", password = "mypassword", private_key_file = "/home/ssh-keys/rsa_key.p8", private_key_file_pwd="myfilepassword", host = "myhost.eastus2.snowflakecomputing.com", opts = list(warehouse = "WAREHSE", db = "DB", schema = "CB", authenticator="externalbrowser"))

jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:snowflake://<account><.region_id>.snowflakecomputing.com", "<username>","<password>")

jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:myhost.eastus2.snowflakecomputing.com", private_key_file = "/home/ssh-keys/rsa_key.p8", private_key_file_pwd="myfilepassword")
```

tried following snowflakes guide here but this just uses username and password which requires the auth verified.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/connecting-r-to-snowflake-using-the-jdbc-driver-mac-os-x
https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/How-TO

Comment: What is the authentication method used for the JDBC user to Snowflake? Based on what you describe it seems you have SSO, then key pair won't probably work. You'll probaly need a user that doesn't uses SSO and setup key pair authentication just for that user.

Comment: sso is in place but as per Dave Weldons comments snowflake apparently supports ssh key access once the key is added to users snowflake profile using the alter command

Answer (score 1):

You will either need a user configured with password authentication or [Key Pair Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html). SSO authentication will not work for you in the absence of a browser. After creating the keys, you will need to [assign the key to the Snowflake user](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html#step-4-assign-the-public-key-to-a-snowflake-user). Finally, here is how to [configure JDBC configuration to use key pair authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#label-jdbc-using-key-pair-authentication)

Comment: thanks for this @Dave Weldon, Ive setup the first 2 pieces but the syntax above does not appear to let me pass the keys in when using jdbc in R, try to clarify if the syntax is correct for using ssh keys , jdbc and R studio

Comment: Your first connection using src_snowflakedb specifies authenticator=externalbrowser. That requires a browser and SSO which does not apply to you. The final connection looks closer to what you need. Instead of the separate parameters for the private key data, try it all in the connection string as follows: jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:myhost.eastus2.snowflakecomputing.com/?private_key_file=/home/ssh-keys/rsa_key.p8&private_key_file_pwd=myfilepassword")

Comment: @DeclanG

Did you get a chance to try the suggestion mentioned above ? If yes please let me know how did you achieve the required output.

I have no knowledge in R but wanted to know whether it is feasible to connect to snowflake using private key through R.